# Append multiple files into one (awk)

Tags: awk

I am trying to dump all files into one file. For this I was using this awk script (reading.awk)

```
BEGIN {

 RS = "\n"
 filename= "DDL_dump.sql"
 flag=1;
}

{
    record =$0
    if(record == ") ;")
        flag = 0;
    else if( flag==1)
        print record >> filename 

}

END {
 close(filename)
}
```

But for every file it is overwriting instead of appending.

Trying to run this from a bat file in same folder as the files.

```
FOR %%i IN (*.sql) DO awk -f reading.awk %%i
```

Comment: Error: `print $record ...` should be `print record ...` I'm not sure if that is the cause since I did not try the code as there was no sample data.

Comment: Nope. Didn't help!

Comment: @codebee: Please show us how you are trying to run this

Comment: Your script looks good to append the output of files. What's your sample input there?

Comment: The scripts does the same as `awk 'BEGIN{f=1} /\) ;/{f=0} f' file1 file2 ... >> 'DDL_dump.sql'`

Comment: @hek2mgl It is not possible for me to give all file names as there are many, hence the bat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want this (without a shell loop):

```
awk 'FNR==1{f=1} /\) ;/{f=0} f' *.sql > 'DDL_dump.sql'
```

Explanation in multiline form:

```
# True for the first line of each file
FNR==1 {
    f=1 # Set f(lag)
}

# Once the pattern occurs ...
/\) ;/ {
    f=0 # ... reset the (f)lag
}

# As long as the f(lag) is true, print the line.
f
```

---

```
*.sql
```

is a shell glob expression that expands to all .sql files in the current folder and will pass them to `awk` as arguments.

```
> 'DDL_dump.sql'
```

is shell output redirection that will store the output of the `awk` command into *DDL_dump.sql*

Comment: Glad to see that it helped.